# Sending writes to the mysql master and reads to slave in slick

Tags: mysql, scala, slick, master-slave, slick-2.0

With Slick and a Master/Slave set up with MySQL, how do I ensure writes (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, etc) are sent to the master and reads (`SELECT`) are send to the slaves?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-replication-connection.html) docs on this, we need to set `Connection#setReadOnly(true|false)`.

A nice way to do this in slick is to add the following functions to your database code:

```
/**
 * Runs a block of read only database code. No transaction required.
 */
def readOnly[T](f: => T) = db withSession {
  Database.threadLocalSession.conn.setReadOnly(true)
  f
}

/**
 * Runs a block of read/write database code in a transaction. 
 * Any exceptions will rollback any writes.
 */
def readWrite[T](f: => T) = db withTransaction {
  Database.threadLocalSession.conn.setReadOnly(false)
  f
}
```

Then you can write queries like so:

```
/**
 * Goes to slave
 */
def findUser(id: String) = readOnly {
  sql"SELECT ... FROM user WHERE id = $id".as[User].firstOption
}

/**
 * Goes to master
 */
def createUser(id: String) = readWrite {
  sqlu"INSERT INTO user VALUES(...)".execute
}
```

Comment: In case you get "java.sql.SQLException: No database selected" when running "Database.threadLocalSession.conn.setReadOnly(false)", this got fixed for me by upgrading to MySQL Connector 5.1.32